# How to retrieve data from mongo collections in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections, fullcalendar

```
Events = new Mongo.Collection('event');
Template.newEvent.onRendered(function(){
        $('.newEvent').validate({
            submitHandler : function() {
                var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
                var module = $('[name="module"]').val();
                var date = event.target.date.value;
                var month = event.target.month.value;
                var year = event.target.year.value;
                var startTime = event.target.startTime.value;
                var endTime = event.target.endTime.value;
                var type = event.target.type.value;
                var description = event.target.description.value;
                Events.insert({
                        module: module.toUpperCase(),
                        date: date,
                        month: month,
                        year: year,
                        startTime: startTime,
                        endTime: endTime,
                        type: type,
                        description: description,
                        createdBy: currentUser,
                        startDate: new Date(year, month-1, date, startTime),
                        endDate: new Date(year, month-1, date, endTime),
                        title: module + " " + type
                    });
                    var print = ("Event Created!\n" +
                        "Module: " + module + "\n" +
                        "Date: " + date + "/" + month + "/" + year + "\n" +
                        "From: " + startTime + "00 To: " + endTime + "00\n" +
                        "Type: " + type + "\n" +
                        "Description: " + description);
                    alert(print);
            }
        })
    });
```

My friend and i tried to create a web app to learn.
So we have created a collection in MongoDB with calendar events as objects. We are making use of FullCalendar API in our web app. However we are unable to retrieve the data in our JavaScript folder in order to put it into calendar API to display our events on the calendar. We were told 
Collections.find({module: "Math"}).month
should work but when we couldn't get it to work and also when we try it at the console it returns undefined.

We were also told to load the data from a PHP file but we are not familiar with uploading the data onto a PHP file before loading it.

Also we tried
Collections.find().toArray() but were still unable to retrieve the information using array[0].startTime, that's already in the database.

Our goal is basically to get user entries and retrieve the String input to create an event on FullCalendar with the given details.

Comment: Have you specified `MONGO_URL`? Like, do you have your MongoDB database set up? Normally we declare/create collections on meteor's server side. Read [this guide](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html) to understand more about how meteor's collections work. Besides, assume you have everything set up already, you should publish the collection from the server side for client side to subscribe the subset of the original collection. Read [this guide](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#publications) to know meteor's pub/sub systems

Answer (score 0):

To fetch only 1 document you have to use `findOne` or `find().fetch()[0]`. 
Besides that, maybe you need to read about [Publications and Data Loading](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html)

```
const myEvent = Events.findOne({module: "Math"});
let month  = myEvent ? myEvent.month : 0
```